# How can I read the file which is created by another apk?

Tags: android, file

My application (A.apk) use openFileOutput to create a file:

```
FileOutputStream os = this.openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

And how can I read this file by another application (B.apk)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read it only if the file is either in the Phone Memory or in the SD-Card it self.

Unlike SharedPreference or Sqlite Database File System is free from application dependency. Meaning File is totally independent from the Android Application. You can create file from one application(.apk) and read it from another android application(.apk). You don't require any special kind of mechanism for this.